# What is the cause of this roll oscillation during BA492 go-around?

Tags: wind, go-around, roll

Earlier today, BA492 aborted a landing at Gibraltar due to a strong tailwind, according to [this article](https://www.airlive.net/breaking-video-emerging-of-british-airways-ba492-fighting-against-cross-wind-this-morning-during-go-around-at-gibraltar/). Videos of the go-around show the Airbus A320 undergoing pronounced oscillation in the roll axis:

[**Content warning**: both videos contain profanities]

What is the cause of such large magnitude oscillations?

Comment: The flaps seem partially extended, would that have any effect?

Comment: It was 'normal' operation - southerly winds create rotors coming off th Rock. This was warned to all aircraft when these wind conditions exist.  The flight crew executed a go around and proceeded to Malaga.

Comment: [This](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3BkOgZPjZX4) video by **Mentour Pilot** explains what happened.